# How to convert integer hours to datetime?

Tags: matlab, datetime

I am trying to read time variable from a netcdf file. 
However, it is not in the correct format.

```
time=ncread('era5_so3.nc','time');
```

The time variable is in Gregorian with units 'hours since 1900-01-01 00:00:00.0'. I tried adding and subtracting `t0` of the same to `time`. But it does not give the right date.

```
t0 = datenum('1900-01-01 00:00:00', 'yyyy-mm-dd HH:MM:SS');
time = time + t0;
time = datetime(time,'ConvertFrom','datenum');

time=[1040928 1040929 1040930 1040931 ...]
```

The actual date should be 1 Oct 2018 and time should come with hourly interval. How can I get the correct date?

Comment: `datenum`s measure in days, so one hour is 1/24. Try dividing your `time` vector by 24.

Comment: This method gives the date right but does not give any time value. All hh:mm:ss shows as 00:00:00. But the date is correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, So I found a post - 
https://au.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/439534-how-to-correct-time

It works -

```
time=ncread('era5_so3.nc','time');
dtime = datetime(1900, 1, 1, time, 0, 0);
```

Answer (score 2):

I *think* what you want is to convert your existing `time` to a [`duration`](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/duration.html), using the [`hours`](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/duration.hours.html) function. So, you want something like this:

```
time = [1 10 100 200]; % for example
t0 = datetime(1900,1,1);
result = t0 + hours(time)
```

Comment: This is what I am doing for the time being. But I need to know what is there is the file.

Answer (score 1):

We know that `datenum` gives decimal dates, thus an hour would be `1/24`. Knowing this, you simply have to divide `time` by 24 to get from hours to decimal days:

```
t0 = datenum('1900-01-01 00:00:00', 'yyyy-mm-dd HH:MM:SS');
time = time/24 + t0;
time = datetime(time,'ConvertFrom','datenum');
```